# How to install NPM packages in Azure release pipeline task?

Tags: npm

I want to run Cypress during the release pipeline. So I run this script to install everything I need:

```
npm init -y
npm install cypress --save-dev
npm install mocha@5.2.0 --save-dev
npm install cypress-multi-reporters --save-dev
npm install mocha-junit-reporters@1.23.6 --save-dev
npm install mocha-multi-reporters@1.1.7 --save-dev
npm install mochawesome@4.0.1 --save-dev
npm install mochawesome-merge@2.0.1 --save-dev
npm install mochawesome-report-generator@4.0.0 --save-dev
```

[image]

This is the output of the task:

[image]

I can't really figure out what's going wrong, why can't I install multiple NPM packages?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the correct way to go about it but I ran a `create file` task:

```
{
  "name": "@asd/suite",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "description": "Embrace React Suite",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "https://dev.azure.com/asd/asd/_git/client",
  "author": "Embrace",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "^3.3.1",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "mocha-junit-reporters": "^1.23.6",
    "mocha-multi-reporters": "^1.1.7",
    "mochawesome": "^4.0.1",
    "mochawesome-merge": "^2.0.1",
    "mochawesome-report-generator": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

This creates a `package.json` file with the dependencies I need and after that I run a `npm install` task. This at least installs everything so I can run Cypress.